ID movie: Highschool boy is bullied into a coma
I watched it many years ago. About 5 years. I saw it english. It seemed to be an american movie set in an occidental lifestyle. 
A highschool boy is bullied by a girl and her friends. They drag him into the woods and fight. He is hit on the head with a sort of metal top bin (like a garbage can top) and falls in a coma. His spirit stays in this world, and appears only to the girl that bullied him. He finds out that she hides her curly hair under a hat to look tough, and that she is the only one who takes care of her young brother. She feels guilty and tries to help him regain his body. They do not know where it is. They fall in love. His best friend tries to kill himself, and temporarily talks to his friend. They find the body beside a river close to the time limit where he can stay alive. Finally, he regains his body and she dies. 

Welcome to the community. That may be enough plot detail, but feel free to add more if you can remember. But please add the following: What year did you watch it? What was the language you saw it in? What year and country do you think it was produced in? Also, in the plot, where did it take place? I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

You're looking for The Invisible. It matches what you described perfectly (but they don't really fall in love).

Nick Powell is an excellent high-school student who raises money by selling homework and results of quizzes to his schoolmates. He aims to travel to London for a writer's course - telling his best friend, Pete Egan, that he has already bought the airplane ticket but he has not told to his mother yet. Annie Newton has a problem with Pete, who owes money to her. As events unfold, due to a case of mistaken identity Nick takes a severe beating from Annie and her gang, his body dumped in a sewer. The next morning, he discovers he cannot be seen - he is now a spirit in a state of limbo and can only observe as the events of that day unfold.





@jasyB Glad you were able to find the movie you were searching for. Please also mark the answer as accepted (checkmark on the left) to formally indicate your question was answered correctly.
